# bundle.js: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack, bundle

I am getting this error even after i have called the jquery file befre the bootstrap.js.
anyone, Kindly  suggest?
I am working with node and angularr and webpack.

My declerations goes like this.

```
require('jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
require('./content/common.css');
require('angular');
```

Pls suggest the cause here!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

May be try loading the jQuery as below :

**window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.js');**

And then,

**var Bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');**